# How to read a specific number of integers and store it in a list in python?

Tags: python

Lets suppose I want to first input the total number of integers I am going to enter. 
N = 5, I must be able to read exactly 5 integers and store it in a list

```
for i in range(5):
    lst = map(int, raw_input().split())
```

doesn't do the job

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Show us a desired output

Comment: You seem to be simultaneously trying to take the input on separate lines and space-separated on the same line. Decide which you want first!

Comment: because you're overwriting the list variable on each iteraction

Comment: Yes, I understand I am overwriting. Trying the below solutions right now :)

Comment: I enter the value of N and press enter. If the entered value is 5, I enter 5 values space separated which are then going to be stored in a list.

Comment: Why does it matter how many? If they're space-separated on a single line, `map(int, raw_input().split())` will get all of them. If you really want to restrict the number, just slice `[:N]` afterwards, or check how many there are and raise an error if `len(lst) != N`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most primitive way, you can do it in following way.

```
n = int(raw_input())
numbers = map(int, raw_input().split())[:n]
```

We can help more if you tell us the context in which you are asking the problem. I doubt if you are using it for some competitive programming problem.

Actually, problem in your code is that you are reading a line and making list from it. But you are doing this **FIVE** times. Also, you can read lot more than five numbers if they are in single line.

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what i needed. Thanks. I am just going to xor the values of the list later. A simple problem to find out the number that doesn't occur twice in a list :)

Comment: @abhidoeslinux Happy to help man. Please accept the answer if you think it solved your problem. Moreover you can use **count function on list** to solve your problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Sa far as I understand, you need the following

```
lst=[]
for n in range(5):
    lst.append(int(raw_input("Input a number: ").split()))
print repr(lst)
```

Comment: Yup i just needed to append [:n] as somone pointed out. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
inp = raw_input    # Python 2.x
# inp = input        # Python 3.x

def get_n_ints(prompt, n):
    while True:    # repeat until we get acceptable input
        s = inp(prompt)
        try:
            vals = [int(i) for i in s.split()]
            if len(vals) == n:
                return vals
            else:
                print("Please enter exactly {} values".format(n))
        except ValueError:
            # a string couldn't be converted to int
            print("Values need to be integers!")
```